# custom single.php not working

Tags: posts, templates, single

Trying to solve this issue for the past hour and I can't figure out what's going on.

Trying to create `single-blog.php` (I have a few posts which are under the category 'blog') but Wordpress automatically redirects these posts to single.php! I've flushed the permalinks by **settings** > **permalink** > **save changes** but still nothing happens. To test & to see if Wordpress picks up on single-blog.php the code I used was:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
     <h1>TEST HERE</h1>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I had the same problem. I solved it by modifying the Permalink  to **`Post name - /%postname%/`**

Comment: can you not use single-post-blog.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) article in the codex, especially pay attention to [Single Post Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) part.

As you can see you have only three options:

1. `single-{post_type}.php`
2. `single.php`
3. `index.php`

It means that you can't create a template for posts related to `blog` category. So you shouldn't use `single-blog.php` template, use `single.php` instead and add there something like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if ( has_category( 'blog' ) : ?>
        <h1>TEST HERE</h1>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1>Else posts</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Also, if you need to customize the single-post display for posts in a particular category, if those changes can be pared down to CSS, then you can take advantage of the CSS classes output by `body_class()` and `post_class()` to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Out of curiosity, when does single-{post_type}.php become relevant if a simple if/else function works?

Comment: @NazarAbubaker if you use custom post type like `product`, then you can use `single-product.php` template for this CPT.